# Create Customized weighted variable in R

Tags: r

My data set looks like this

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(ITEMID = 101:120,DEPT = c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)),
                   CLASS = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                   SUBCLASS = c(3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4),
                   PRICE = sample(1:20,20),UNITS = sample(1:100,20)
                   )


> data
   ITEMID DEPT CLASS SUBCLASS PRICE UNITS
1     101    1     1        3     6    94
2     102    1     1        3     8    22
3     103    1     1        3    11    64
4     104    1     1        3    16    13
5     105    1     1        4     4    26
6     106    1     2        4    14    37
7     107    1     2        4    15     2
8     108    1     2        4     9    36
9     109    1     2        4    19    81
10    110    1     2        3     1    31
11    111    2     1        3     3    44
12    112    2     1        3     2    54
13    113    2     1        3    20    90
14    114    2     1        3    10    17
15    115    2     1        3     5    72
16    116    2     2        4     7    57
17    117    2     2        4    12    67
18    118    2     2        4    17     9
19    119    2     2        4    18    60
20    120    2     2        4    13    34
```

Now I want to add another column called PRICE_RATIO using the following logic

Taking ItemID 101 and group_by with DEPT,CLASS and SUBCLASS yields prices `c(6,8,11,16)` and UNITS `c(94,22,64,13)` for ITEMIDs `c(101,102,103,104)` respectively

Now for each item id the variable PRICE_RATIO will be the ratio of the price of that item id to weighted price of all other itemIDs in the group. For example

For item ID `101` other items are `c(102,103,104)` whose total UNITS is `(22+ 64+13) =99` and weights are `(22/99,64/99,13/99)`. So weighted price for all other items is `(22/99)*8 + (64/99)*11 + (13/99)*16 = 10.9899`. Hence value for PRICE_RATIO will be `6/10.9899= .54`

Similarly for all other items.

Any help in creating the code for this will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to your problem, and generally such problems can be with the use of `dplyr` package and its data munging capabilities. The logic here is as you say, you group by the desired columns, then mutate the desired value (sum product of price and units (excluding the product for that specific row) and ratio of price to that weight. You can execute every step in this computation separately (I encourage that so you can learn) and see exactly what it does.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(DEPT, CLASS, SUBCLASS) %>%
  mutate(price_ratio = round(PRICE /
                             ((sum(UNITS * PRICE) - UNITS * PRICE) /
                              (sum(UNITS) - UNITS)),
                             2))
```

Output is as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [20 x 7]
Groups: DEPT, CLASS, SUBCLASS [6]

   ITEMID  DEPT CLASS SUBCLASS PRICE UNITS price_ratio
    <int> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <int>       <dbl>
1     101     1     1        3     6    94        0.55
2     102     1     1        3     8    22        0.93
3     103     1     1        3    11    64        1.50
4     104     1     1        3    16    13        1.99
5     105     1     1        4     4    26         NaN
6     106     1     2        4    14    37        0.88
7     107     1     2        4    15     2        0.97
8     108     1     2        4     9    36        0.52
9     109     1     2        4    19    81        1.63
10    110     1     2        3     1    31         NaN
11    111     2     1        3     3    44        0.29
12    112     2     1        3     2    54        0.18
13    113     2     1        3    20    90        4.86
14    114     2     1        3    10    17        1.08
15    115     2     1        3     5    72        0.46
16    116     2     2        4     7    57        0.48
17    117     2     2        4    12    67        0.93
18    118     2     2        4    17     9        1.36
19    119     2     2        4    18    60        1.67
20    120     2     2        4    13    34        1.03
```